# ProviderError: HttpProviderError

Tags: solidity, hardhat

**I got The following error, when i try to send a transaction for funding charity**

after i deployed the contract, i ran this command **npx hardhat run scripts/fund.js --network localhost**
and i got the following error

```bash
ProviderError: HttpProviderError
    at HttpProvider.request (F:\fullstack-auction\smart-contract\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:83:19)
    at AutomaticSenderProvider.request (F:\fullstack-auction\smart-contract\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:344:34)
    at FixedGasProvider.request (F:\fullstack-auction\smart-contract\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\gas-providers.ts:28:34)
    at FixedGasPriceProvider.request (F:\fullstack-auction\smart-contract\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\gas-providers.ts:54:34)
    at ChainIdValidatorProvider.request (F:\fullstack-auction\smart-contract\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\chainId.ts:66:34)
    at BackwardsCompatibilityProviderAdapter.send (F:\fullstack-auction\smart-contract\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\backwards-compatibility.ts:36:27)      
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (F:\fullstack-auction\smart-contract\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:48)
    at F:\fullstack-auction\smart-contract\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:255:34
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

this is my hardhat.config

```js
  require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("hardhat-deploy")
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
require("hardhat-contract-sizer")
require("dotenv").config()

const GOERLI_RPC_URL = process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL
const BSC_RPC_URL = process.env.BSC_RPC_URL

const BSC_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.BSC_PRIVATE_KEY
const GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    // localhost: {
    //   chainId: 31337,
    //   allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
    //   gas: 2100000,
    //   gasPrice: 8000000000,
    // },
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 31337,
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
      gas: 2100000,
      gasPrice: 8000000000,
    },
    goerli: {
      url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 5,
    },
    binance: {
      url: BSC_RPC_URL,
      chainId: 0x61,
      accounts: [BSC_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
  // gasReporter: {
  //   enabled: true,
  //   currency: "USD",
  //   outputFile: "./gas-report.txt",
  //   noColors: true,
  //   // coinmarketcap: process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
  // },
  contractSizer: {
    runOnCompile: false,
    only: ["Charity"],
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [{ version: "0.8.7" }, { version: "^0.8.0" }],
  },
}
```

And this my deploy script

```js
 const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")
const { networkConfig, developmentChains } = require("../helper.hardhat.config")

const liveWallet = "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266"

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
  const chainId = network.config.chainId
  let fundWallet

  if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    fundWallet = networkConfig[chainId].walletFund
  } else {
    fundWallet = liveWallet
  }

  const args = [
    fundWallet,
    ethers.utils.parseEther(networkConfig[chainId].minimumFund),
  ]

  log("deploying ...")
  const charity = await deploy("Charity", {
    from: deployer,
    args,
    log: true,
  })

  log("deployed successfull at", charity.address)
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "charity"]
```

And this one is my transaction scripts

```js
   const { ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")
const { networkConfig } = require("../helper.hardhat.config")

const charity = ethers.utils.parseEther("3")

async function fund() {
  const { deployer } = getNamedAccounts()
  const charityContract = await ethers.getContract("Charity", deployer)
  const funding = await charityContract.fundingCharity({
    value: charity,
  })
  await funding.wait(1)
  const getFund = await charityContract.getFundingBalance()

  console.log(getFund.toString())
}

fund().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
  process.exitCode = 1
})
```

i'm trying to test send transaction for funding charity function on my contract

Comment: Did you create the `.env` file?

Comment: yes i did, i saved my RPC_URL and others in my .env file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created a `.env` file and defined the environment variables:
`GOERLI_RPC_URL`, `GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY`, `BSC_RPC_URL`, `BSC_PRIVATE_KEY`.
For goerli RPC URL value you can use: `https://eth-goerli.api.onfinality.io/public`
For the private key you have to export private key from your testnet account in your wallet application and make sure you have some balance in that account.

The following approach would work:

**hardhat.config.js**

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config()

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
const GOERLI_RPC_URL = process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL
const BSC_RPC_URL = process.env.BSC_RPC_URL

const BSC_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.BSC_PRIVATE_KEY
const GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    // localhost: {
    //   chainId: 31337,
    //   allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
    //   gas: 2100000,
    //   gasPrice: 8000000000,
    // },
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 31337,
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
      gas: 2100000,
      gasPrice: 8000000000,
    },
    goerli: {
      url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 5,
    },
    binance: {
      url: BSC_RPC_URL,
      chainId: 0x61,
      accounts: [BSC_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
  // gasReporter: {
  //   enabled: true,
  //   currency: "USD",
  //   outputFile: "./gas-report.txt",
  //   noColors: true,
  //   // coinmarketcap: process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
  // },
  contractSizer: {
    runOnCompile: false,
    only: ["Charity"],
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [{ version: "0.8.17" }],
  },
}
```

(Assuming the solidity code is compiled for version 0.8.17)

**deploy.js**

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

  // adjust the arguments any way you like
  let fundWallet = "0x922F709CE161b2B80fc626f65bAA52112752489A"
  const minimumFund = hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001");

  const Charity = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Charity");
  const charity = await Charity.deploy(fundWallet, minimumFund);

  await charity.deployed();

  console.log(
    ` deployed to ${charity.address}`
  );
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Running the following command would deploy the contract to `Goerli` testnet:

`npx hardhat run --network goerli scripts/deploy.js`

(Assuming the `deploy.js` file in `<root directory>/scripts` folder)

Comment: im already solved it brother, but thanks for your help